# How to remove duplicates from loop results in Python Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have Python Data Frame like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID1" : [1,2,3], "ID2" : [44,55,66]})
```

Then I create loop like below:

```
s_list = list()
t_list = list()

for s in df["ID1"].values:
    for t in df["ID2"].values:
        s_list.append(s)
        t_list.append(t)
        
        result = pd.DataFrame()
        result["res1"] = s_list
        result["res2"] = t_list
result
```

Neverheless result of this loop is like below:

[image]

And I need to repare this loop so as to acheive result like this (so identical combination ID1 x ID2 like in df):

[image]

Comment: [`df.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)??

Comment: there is no duplicates, I need to change loop, implement some changes in loop no outisde loop

Comment: I am really not following what you are after in the results dataframe.  Could you make it a little more clear?

Comment: You must avoid using for loop while manipulating a data frame. Use built-in functions as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try the pandas `.to_list()` method instead of a using loop.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID1" : [1,2,3], "ID2" : [44,55,66]})
s_list = df["ID1"].to_list()
t_list = df["ID2"].to_list()
```

The result is the following:

```
s_list = [1, 2, 3]
t_list = [44, 55, 66]
```

Both `s_list` and `t_list` are now lists. Test it out by `print(type(your_list))` which results in `<class 'list'>`

Comment: ehhh ok but I need it to do in the loop, man it is obvious to use to_list